# System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser and LoadCompleted for (i)Frames?

Tags: c#, browser

Is it possible to be notified if the location of an frame or iframe of an document in my System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser changes?

LoadCompleted does not work for (i)frames.

Answer (score 0):

Try the WebBrowser.[Navigated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigated.aspx) event.